# Predicting package version

Tags: puppet

I'm configuring syslog-ng through puppet on my servers. The configuration files are very different between versions 2.x, 3.1 and 3.3 . On my hosts, depending on the operating system (centos5, centos6, debian 7, ubuntu), the available syslog-ng version will vary.

I had 2 ideas to adapt the configuration of syslog-ng to the correct version :

- Custom Fact : It's easy to write a custom fact to test the installed version of syslog-ng. But this fact will be useless if syslog-ng is not already installed.
- Conditions in the manifest : I find it a bit ugly to define a "case" in the manifest wich would determine the version of syslog-ng that the operatingsystem provides.

For me, the cleanest way to do this is to test which version of the package is available through the operatingsystem before installation.
A facter could do this, but I guess it would be a bit difficult.

Is there a puppetish way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed puppet-ish way to solve this problem!

You can combine `$::osfamily` with `$::operatingsystemrelease` to do something like this in your manifests:

```
case $::osfamily {
  'CentOS': { 
    case $::operatingsystemrelease {
       /^6/: { include syslog-ng::centos6 }
       /^5/: { include syslog-ng::centos5 }
       default: { notice("This operating system release for CentOs '${::operatingsystemrelease}' is not supported.")
    }
   }
   default:  { notice "Unsupported osfamily ${::osfamily}" }
}
```

Comment: Having a subclass for each case seems clean. Though you have to know in advance wich distribution ships which version of the package, and I would have liked to avoid this knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood all of your problem. In any case, one can use puppet `package` type to ensure a particular version and use `$lsbdistdescription` to get the OS name. For example :

```
package { 'syslog-ng' :
    ensure => $::lsbdistdescription {
    '/CentOS 7/': => "3.2",
    '/CentOS 6/': => "3.1",
    '/(Debian|Ubuntu)/' => "2.x",
    default => "latest",
   },
}
```

NOTE: In the above one has to get the exact name of the OS, i.e. `CentOS 7 or CentOS 6 or Ubuntu` from each OS. You can do that by executing `facter --puppet | grep lsbdistdescription` on the OS. I don't have variety of machines, so I couldn't check that exactly.

Then the configuration file can be just one sourced from a template. The template will vary based on the OS.

```
file { 'file.cfg' :
    ensure => "present",
    content => template("modulename/file.erb"),
    require => Package["syslog-ng"],
}
```

Hope it helps.